# Sort text files for web site view

Tags: html

How can I program a web site to list the 20 newest txt files (out of many more) in a directory and display them in order of newest to oldest and then link those files for web site viewing.

Comment: you can't do this with just html

Answer (score 1):

This is impossible to do with bare HTML. You'll need a server-side language (such as PHP) to help you with this.

Comment: And the languages available to you depend on how the server is configured.